# Can I pull signature of team member from outlook while sending out email from Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi, connect-for-outlook, salesforce-outlook-sync

Thoughts on the below challenge?

Can I pull the signature of a team member from Outlook while sending out an email from Marketing Cloud?

The components of the signature are the Image (photo), Name, and Phone number (with extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“No” would be the quick and easy answer. Did you search for any APIs in O365 allowing you to access signatures on particular email accounts?

Image would also need to be exported to a publicly available URL, as it normally is embedded in the email by Outlook… so indeed, far from feasible.

Comment: ok thank you @Lukas_Lunow, this helps.